# В чем заключается данная ошибка

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго Времени суток начал изучать flutter. При добавлении кнопки возникает эта ошибка. Не могу разобраться в чем причина. Гуглил, на ресурсах похожий код. Был бы благодарен если объясните в чем тут проблема.

Comment: Код следует вставлять текстом.

Answer (score 0):

Там не нужно двоеточие!

```js
  onPressed() {
    print("1234")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
onPressed: () => {
  print("1234");
}
```

или

```dart
onPressed: () {
  print("1234");
}
```

Не хватало точки с запятой, об этом указано в ошибках:
Не найдена ';' в строке 21, символ 25.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]